# What is the difference between pointers to array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I came across these two terms 
Int (*q)[3][4]  and. int q[ ][3][4].
What's the difference these two terms?
And one more question .

```
 Char a[ ]="abcd";
  Char *p="abv";
   a="ghj";
   p="ajk";
 Printf("℅s℅s",a,p);
```

Why this would not compile?

Comment: `Will this run or not and why?` Well, did you try to run it?

Comment: This wouldn't even compile, let alone run.

Comment: You are taking too many liberties with the cases of various keywords and standard functions. I don't think any conscientious C programmer can overlook that in your question and don't at least flinch while writing an answer...

Comment: You're trying to determine the difference between pointers and arrays. This article is technical and you should read it, it's really good! http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c

Comment: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to `char *`

Comment: are you asking why a is not compiling while p does?

Comment: a is an array and it can be modified using subscripts a[0] ... a[size-1], not doing this directly a="whatever". p is a pointer to const string placed somewhere in memory. Since the string is constant it can't be modified directly.

Comment: @cameltoe yes I am asking the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't compile because of the line:

```
a = "ghi"
```

This assigns a const char* to a char* directly. You can use strcpy to copy the string intead:

```
strcpy(a, "ghi")
```

You will still have warnings at this point, because you have not declared p as a const. You can fix this like so:

```
const char* p = "abv"
```